# TabHost with Fragment not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my FragmentActivity with a NavigationDrawer, and in that i call my fragment, for example:

```
case 3:
fragment = new Edit();
break;
```

now, in Edit fragment i want, (if possible), have a tab view with 2 fragment inside. So i set my Edit fragment with:

```
public class Edit extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager());

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                EditSource.class, savedInstanceState);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                EditSource.class, savedInstanceState);


        return mTabHost;
    }



 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mTabHost = null;
    }
```

EditSource is another fragment.
The app work, but when i go in Edit fragment i see the Tab view but i don't see the EditSource fragment inside that only black..sorry for my english.

[image: Screenshot example]